# How do I display the full content even the window is resized?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, resize

I want my text and images to be displayed fully even when the browser window is resized to any size. So far it works when [I resize the window horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpMxd.jpg) but when I resize it vertically,
[it just clips over the content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfTKK.jpg)

I don't want any side scrollbars either, thus the resized content.

```css
body {
  background-color: #CFFFE7;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#master {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 30px 70px 60px 70px;
  height: 100%;

}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#diagrams {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo-image img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="master" class="container">
  <p>This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence.</p>
  <p>
    This is a very long sentence.
    <br/>
    This is a very long sentence.
  </p>
  <div id="diagrams" class="container">
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img id="ssc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img id="msc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img id="asc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image "/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because when you are resizing window vertically, it is not affecting the height of **.logo-image** div.

You can use **vh** attribute with your **.logo-image** div as shown below :

```
.logo-image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height : 90vh;
}
```

**vh** basically represents percentage of view port, so if we are assigning 90vh as height to some div, then it means 90% of available viewport will be assigned to it as height.

Comment: I used vh for `.logo-image`, but now the position of the images is affected too. [Here's the snip.](https://imgur.com/a/B7U4K)

Do I have to apply the vh to the `.master` container instead?

Comment: You can try applying that to the appropriate element which fits your requirement, you might need to change other CSS as well, in order too fit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to adjust the third line of your CSS and change "overflow: hidden;":

```
body {
    background-color: #CFFFE7;
    /* overflow: hidden; THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM REMOVE IT*/
    /* optional: if above doesn't work, add overflow: scroll; */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

You can hide your scrollbar like so:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Or hide ALL scrollbars like so:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: I don't have much problems with the scrollbar since I can just hide it with `overflow: hidden` but the images are still cut off.

Comment: It still produces the same results though! Or am I missing out something crucial

Comment: I see what you're saying, I replicated your html/css on codepen:
https://codepen.io/wade-labs/pen/ZXWgex , I think you just need to play around with the px ratio on your media queries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the solution. Please check the result if it matches your requirement!

Here is a JSFiddle.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Changes made:**

1. `Body` and `html` have been set to 100vh (which means the size of the visible screen only!), the body has a default margin of 8px, this is set to zero.
2. The second major change is incorporating `box-sizing: border-box;` this property will ensure whatever padding is added with be included in the total height of the element, this is crucial for preventing the scrollbar in the screen.
3. I have included a div with classes `wrapper` and `clearfix`, the wrapper class is used to position the images in the center of the screen. The clearfix is because, when we use floating elements (`the images are set to float:left;`) the height of the parent is lost, this can be prevented by using the `clearfix` class
4. The height of the element with id `diagram` should be set to `height:auto` till the container height is greater than the window height; if this condition is satisfied we need to use `height:80%`. This is done by the following media query.

**CSS:**

```
#diagrams {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 420px) {
  #diagrams {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Here is the screen height is greater than 420px, the height of the ID `diagrams` is set to `auto`, else its set to `80%`.

Let me know if there are any more issues.

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #CFFFE7;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#master {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 70px 60px 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 10%;
}

#diagrams {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 420px) {
  #diagrams {
    height: auto;
  }
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo-image img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE7 */
```

```html
<div id="master" class="container">
  <p>This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence.</p>
  <p>
    This is a very long sentence.
    <br/> This is a very long sentence.</p>
  <div id="diagrams" class="container">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <img id="ssc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="logo-image">
        <img id="msc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="logo-image">
        <img id="asc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image " />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the image to be proportionate instead? I was thinking that the results would go like this if you resize it vertically. [Something like this](https://imgur.com/a/Y1ufW) (I photo edited the image so you can get a clearer idea of what I'm going for)
Do I have to make changes to the whole container instead?

Comment: @Tako From the snapshot I understand the problem, you need to play around with the media queries and handle all the possible screensizes, Here is another version, there are a lot of possiblities so I am unable to tackle all of them, check this one out [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1obnaf64/)